# React Navigation Bottom Tab Bar backPress handling

Tags: react-native

I am going to make the current route back to the previous route after pressing the back button.

For example: there are 5 bottom tabs which are call Page1,Page2,Page3,Page4,Page5, and the initialRouteName is Page1

Assume i browse Page1->Page2->Page3->Page4 , i expect the result is Page4->Page3->Page2->Page1 when i keep pressing the back button. But the final result is Page4 -> Page1.

How can i achieve this? Is is using redux to store the browse recording and set the BackHandler for Android or do some logic for IOS to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use React Native Router Flux.
In this link you have all steps to install it and use it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux
I hope it works you!